# Is there only one way to get a Birthday Cake?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

I know that I should be able to get a Birthday Cake by using DQVC on my birthday (according to the DS's calendar).  Is there any *other* way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have reported it showing up randomly in the DQVC when it was not their birthday, so it is possible to get cake without either waiting for your birthday or changing the date on the DS.

Comment: I've also read that Angelo (a Special Guest the Stornway Inn) will give you a cake on your birthday.